# How to load data dump in particular database schema

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-schema, pg-dump

I'm using Postgres and I have a SQL dump (which has only public schema data). Now, I want to load dump data into particular "xxx" schema (This is other database). How can i do this ?

Comment: Is that a SQL dump (`pg_dump -Fp`)  or a custom format (`pg_dump -Fc`) dump ?

Comment: Yes, it's SQL dump

Comment: Here, I'm using this command to getting dump :- pg_dump -U postgres -h localhost -d dbname > filename.sql